# How can one user see replay on email sent from another user when both are using same email account

Tags: email, email-client

So I have several users that are using same email account. (My email server is Mdeamon) They are having difficulties working this way because when email arrives and one user replays, other users can't see the content of the replay message. Is there some way I can configure some of the email clients like Thunderbird or similar so this problem can be override?

Comment: are you saving sent messages to an accessible place?

Comment: So users can see only messages that they sent. If you are asking me that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you need to move to an IMAP or similar mailbox system, rather than what appears to be a POP3 system.

IMAP will have an 'online' shared mailbox, which your users can access, when a message is sent, the saved messages are available to all users, rather than just the sending user.